# LoadRunner Forms Authentication cookie expired

Tags: forms, authentication, cookies, loadrunner

While load testing using loadrunner all my virtual users are getting logged off from application after 30 min. Looking in detail came to know that authentication cookie is getting expired even though we have continuous activity performed by users.

Now we are trying to update the cookie explicitly after each action to prevent expiration, but not sure how server identifies that authentication cookie is expired. The cookie has only encrypted text and no explicit title mentioning expiry time.

What information in cookie should be updated in authentication cookie to prevent it from expiring?

Cookie Information:

Cookie:

> .ASPXAUTH=66DD4AB74239F00D553BA9640D3AD3F284F47DEC315FD6789AE3FB8D67D2A46A4E89EDB45845C921A7557BD6B39A12EE07188D1009D581AA7AAF6743710653AE44EEF2733CC16082C595D7AE7C73D3E7E3D44BA1BAEEFEB1BF5F98B35C5F8429670FFDD5586E03BB3138C5B78945D82702BDD7C4;
>   path=/; HttpOnly

Answer (score 0):

Tell us how you are managing session state in your script.  Generally if you are cleaning all cookies and instantiating a new session for each iteration you should not run into this.  If you are attempting to maintain some sort of singular session state for the entire length of your test I could see how the server would potentially kick you out after your original session technically logged out of the system (as part of a business process).

Also, do you have explicit cookies noted in your script?   If so, you may want to consider commenting these statements out as LoadRunner will manage cookies automatically.   As part of your burn in consider running a singular virtual user for 30 minutes to an hour to see if you experience this on a single virtual user level.   It's a lot easier to fix for a single user and then projecting to load than it is to try and figure out what is happening across dozens or hundreds of users experiencing a similar issue.

Comment: I have not handled cookies explicitly in my script and thought Loadrunner will handle them automatically.

Comment: I have not handled cookies explicitly in my script and thought Loadrunner will handle them automatically. This particular authentication forms cookie is getting set in Vuser init action which will get called only once per user. I am not sure how this cookie is getting reset when user performs actions in application or why the cookie is not getting update when Vuser is performing the action in Loadrunner. Are cookies set in Vuser Init section wont get updated on each iteration?  Is there anyway where we can capture and correlate forms cookie related information ?

Comment: "Are cookies set in Vuser Init section wont get updated on each iteration?"    Yes, the vuser_init() is only executed once at the startup for each user and is not executed again for each iteration.   You may want to review the documentation sections related to the use of vuser_init(), Action() and vuser_end() associated with scheduling and handling of events.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather the Server keeps track of the expiry time of the cookies, and it's also the server that updates the expiry time, meaning you as the client have no control over this.

I assume the flow is this:

```
The browser or LoadRunner Script will always send the cookie and the
server then verifies it's expiry time on the server side, redirecting
you to the login page if it has expired.
```

I've had this happen to me, and solved it by visiting a special page on the server that "updated the client session expiry time". Perhaps you have a similar situation?